# Is it possible to replace the \mathbbm letters with less grainy ones?

Tags: fonts, packages, metafont, amssymb, amsfonts

Using the `bbm` package, one can generate letters that look like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}
$\mathbbm{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, this has a really low resolution and looks unpleasant at a certain font size. If I put this image into Adobe Illustrator and trace it, the result is a much clearer looking letter:

[image]

While this isn't perfect, it would be good enough for my purposes. 
So is there a way to manually replace `bbm` characters with adjusted ones? Or any other workaround that would enable utilizing the traced character instead of the  character?

Comment: the bbm fonts are only available as bitmap fonts as far as I know, can you not use a different double struck, such as amsfonts `\mathbb`  or stix which are available as scalable fonts?

Comment: As an alternative, you could use `\mathbb{A}` with the `amssymb` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the bbm fonts are bitmap fonts generated by MetaFont. If other double struck fonts are suitable many are available in scalable formats eg `\mathbb` font from the AMS but if you really want `\mathbb` then

Your log will show:

```
  .texlive2019/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/bbm/bbm10.600pk
```

That is a 600dp bitmap tweaked for an HP laserjet 4 printer (which you are probably not using:-)

[image]

If you modify the file to

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{bbm}
\pdfpkresolution=1200
\begin{document}
$\mathbbm{A}$
\end{document}
```

The first time you run it metafont will fire up and make a higher resolution bitmap

```
 .texlive2019/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ultre/public/bbm/bbm10.1200pk
```

[image]

You can only choose resolutions that are in modes.mf

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/metafont/misc/modes.mf
```

so if you need really high resolution you may need to supply an additional mode definition.

Comment: This gives great results at *one* resolution, but will be less than optimal when used in an environment that can be zoomed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton depends on your pdf renderer if you have a high enough bitmap resolution then it should make a reasonable attempt at interpolating a reasonable range of zooms to the screen resolution.

Comment: @barbarabeeton no different to the smooth A in the question  which is a bitmap, and zooms OK in my browser

Comment: Really a bitmap?  I doubt it -- "If I put this image into Illustrator and trace it, the result is a much clearer looking letter:"  Last I knew, Illustrator generated outlines.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it's a bitmap by the time it is on this site. On my screen at current zoom in is a png file with resolution reported by firefox as 851px × 787px (scaled to 676px × 625px)

Comment: This appears to be an adequate workaround. I am however using MikTex, where can I find the `modes.mf` file there?

Comment: I assume miktex has kpsewhich? so `kpsewhich modes.mf` would tell you but I would expect that it is metafont/misc/modes.mf  from the root of your main texmf tree or ctan has a copy http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/modes/modes.mf

Comment: Oh, okay -- not thinking about the conversion here to png.  But in the past, I *have* seen screen images rendered with jaggies after downsampling from high-res bitmaps; much more obvious when tight curves are involved, but the "A" has mostly straight lines.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I found the file using that command. Do you also happen to know which entry exactly I would have to modify to generate higher resolution versions of the letters? I find 29 `1200` entries, but can't determine which one is related to the `bbm` font.

Comment: @Skydiver they are all related to all fonts, just pick the highest number you see (I originally guessed 2400 but there was no mode for that so it defaulted back to ljfour at 600) at high resolutions there is very little difference between the modes, really metafont modes are all about tweaking serifs and hairlines on low resolution printers

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've just replaced all of the values, and that worked. However, there appears to be no difference between 2600 and 9600, so I guess there is a limit somewhere. The obtained resolution is however enough for my needs, so thank you very much!

Comment: I wonder why, even after all these years, `amsfonts` still doesn't have `\mathbb{1}`.  For many mathematicians, we use béackboar bold 1 to denote an indicator function.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the `dsfont` package.  I'll use it from now on instead of `bbm`.

Answer (score 11):

This is just to honorably mention the `dsfont` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\verb|\usepackage{bbm}| & \verb|\mathbbm| & $\mathbbm{A}$ \\ 
\verb|\usepackage{dsfont}| & \verb|\mathds| & $\mathds{A}$ \\ 
\verb|\usepackage{amsfonts}| & \verb|\mathbb| & $\mathbb{A}$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: but what if I really really really want /A not A\

Comment: @davidcarlisle \reflectbox will make you happy 

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat as in the cat is alive and dead? reflecting a character is changing it few of them are symetrical :-) but I guess you have been joking

Answer (score 5):

You can load many different `\mathbb` alphabets using [the `mathalpha` package,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) or if you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, [`unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf#18).  All are outline, rather than bitmap, fonts.

After loading the package and your fonts of choice, write `\mathbb{A}`.